# Unknown action:The action 'rsvp' could not be found for PostsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm getting the error stated in the title. What code would I have to write in my Postscontroller to fix this? I'm not sure what I would have to do here, would I have to define rsvp in my post controller? If thats the case how would I go about doing that?

```
class RsvpController < ApplicationController
 def create
    rsvp = current_user.rsvps.build({post_id: params[:id]})
    if rsvp.save 
    end
 end

end
```

**Show.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <strong>Date:</strong>
  <%= @post.date %>
</p>
<p>where:<%=@post.longitude %>, <%=@post.latitude%></p>

<p>
    <strong>Name:</strong>
    <%= @post.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>User_id:</strong>
  <%= @post.user_id %>
</p>


<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @post.description %>
</p>

<% if current_user == @post.user %>
 <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%end%>
 <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>

<%= button_to "Rsvp now", rsvp_post_path(@post), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  resources :posts
  devise_for :users
  root 'home#index'
  get 'home/ruby_meetup'

  resources :posts do
  post 'rsvp', on: :member
  end
```

Also I want it so it shows the list of people who already rsvped for the event. How would I go about doing that? I would appreciate some help as I'm still learning rails and this is my first project.

Answer (score 0):

By the following line, you define the route:

```
resources :posts do
  post 'rsvp', on: :member
end
```

By this line you're requesting this route:

To process the request, you need a controller action `rsvp`, which actually the error states.
Thus, just define the action (method) and process the request:

```
class RsvpController < ApplicationController
  def create
    rsvp = current_user.rsvps.build({post_id: params[:id]})
    if rsvp.save 
    end
  end

  def rsvp
    # process the request here...
  end
end
```

Comment: how would I go about defining it? Sorry I'm quite new to rails.

Comment: @automationprogramming10 To be honest, I don't know. It completely depends on the logic of your application